# Laravel Customers and Admins store in Userstable

Tags: database, laravel, database-design

I have a database design question. I am building a small customized shop with Laravel. I have the table users. In this table I store the customers but also the admins. With spatie I take over the role management. I want to implement two separate dashboards. A own customer dashboard and own admin dashboard.

For this case, is it a good idea to have customers and admins in one table? What is recommended practice? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I think that is question of personal preferences. Using a package like that you can maintain separation of responsibilities and permissions without any additional risk and, with an unique login procedure to maintain.
Some developers should prefer to create separate tables for that but I really can't see it as a great benefit.
Eventually you should tune your login redirects procedure to show the appropriate dashboard according to user profile